# Prohibit access to the private variable

Tags: c#

I have a private variable `money` that i use with a property `Money`:

```
private int money = 200;
public int Money
{
    get
    {
        return money;
    }
    set
    {
        money = value;
        UpdateMoneyText();
    }
}
```

My problem: i still can access `money` within that class. Is there a protection level, so that i can't use `money` inside the same class?

What i already tried is: using different protection levels that i know, like private, but obivously they don't work.

Comment: No, there is not. I name property backing fields e.g. `_money` to reduce the risk of accidentally accessing them when I meant to access `Money`. See the proposal at [#133](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/133)

Comment: *"My problem: i still can access money within that class."* -- *Why* is that a problem? Are you trying to protect the variable from being misused by yourself as the developer of the class?

Comment: By word 'access' do you mean that you're still able to set it without using the property setter? Is that the main issue?

Comment: It is not possible at the moment.

Comment: No you can't, and there really is no good reason to disallow it. Its your source code file, if you don't want to access it just don't access it. You consumers shouldn't have access to change the internal implementation details of your classes. If you're worried about other team members changing it just leave a comment.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to make sure all value assignment to money must go through the Money setter, then the MoneyText is always sync with the value. To do this, you should do.

```
   public int Money {get;set;}
   public int MoneyText => Money + " USD";
```

And when accessing MoneyText, you always have up-to-date text.

Comment: I like this approach best because if there isn't a need for a separate private backing variable, then the simplest approach is to just not have one..

Comment: This approach works in cases when there's no need for extra setter logic, but given the OP's question, there **is** a need for it, so this won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Not with a keyword, no. Alternatively, you could use Inheritance to create a hidden private variable that could only be modified through it's public getter/setter, like so:

```cs
public class ObjectBase {
  private int money;
  public int Money {
    get
    {
        return money;
    }
    set
    {
        money = value;
        UpdateMoneyText();
    }
  }
}

public class YourClass : ObjectBase {
  public void SomeMethod(int newMoney) {
    this.Money = newMoney; // setter used here, because this.money is inaccessible
  }
}
```

Comment: Because OP specifically stated disallowing access in his class, this seems like the most appropriate response. It accomplishes the specific task the OP was trying to accomplish.